# How do I find the min() or max() of two Option[Int]

Tags: scala, max, min, scala-option

How would you find `minValue` below?
I have my own solution but want to see how others would do it.

```
val i1: Option[Int] = ...
val i2: Option[Int] = ...
val defaultValue: Int = ...
val minValue = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
val minValue = List(i1, i2).flatten match {
  case Nil => defaultValue
  case xs => xs.min
}
```

I'd avoid `sorted` since sorting requires a lot more processing than simply finding the max or min (although it probably doesn't make much difference in this case).

Comment: I think this is probably the best way, though it's unfortunate that the idiomatic style makes it four lines long. I tried to shorten it (by removing match) and came up with `((xs:List[Int]) => {if (xs == Nil) defaultValue else xs.min})(List(i1, i2).flatten)` but this is clearly obfuscation for the sake of brevity.

Comment: why not `List(Option(defaultValue), i1, i2).flatten.min` ?

Comment: flatten.min would throw an UnsupportedOperationException with empty.min if List is empty, when you flatten you can end up with an empty list if all elements inside the list are None

Answer (score 9):

Update: I just noticed that my solution below and the one in your answer behave differently—I read your question as asking for the minimum of the two values *when there are two values*, but in your answer you're effectively treating `None` as if it contained a value that's either bigger (for `min`) or smaller (for `max`) than anything else.

To be more concrete: if `i1` is `Some(1)` and `i2` is `None`, my solution will return the default value, while yours will return 1.

If you want the latter behavior, you can use the default semigroup instance for `Option[A]` and the [tropical semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry) for `Int`. In Scalaz 7, for example, you'd write:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

optionMonoid(Semigroup.minSemigroup[Int]).append(i1, i2) getOrElse defaultValue
```

Or the following shorthand:

```
Tags.Min(i1) |+| Tags.Min(i2) getOrElse defaultValue
```

It's not as clean as the applicative functor solution below, but if that's your problem, that's your problem.

---

Here's a more idiomatic way that doesn't involve creating an extra list:

```
(for { x <- i1; y <- i2 } yield math.min(x, y)) getOrElse defaultValue
```

Or, equivalently:

```
i1.flatMap(x => i2.map(math.min(x, _))) getOrElse defaultValue
```

What you're doing is "lifting" a two-place function (`min`) into an applicative functor (`Option`). [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) makes this easy with its applicative builder syntax:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

(i1 |@| i2)(math.min) getOrElse defaultValue
```

The standard library solution isn't much less elegant in this case, but this is a useful abstraction to know about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Travis. It's pleasing in its brevity, though there's two things that turn me off using it: it uses a third party library, and in order to understand it I need to read an article about "a relatively new area in mathematics and algebraic geometry".

Comment: I added a little more actual way using **cats** for that.

Answer (score 6):

I solved a similar problem using the following approach. We handle a special case when both of the options have values, otherwise we use an API method `Option.orElse`.

```
val a: Option[Int]  = Some(10)
val b: Option[Int] = Some(20)
val c: Option[Int] = (a, b) match {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(x min y)
  case (x, y) => x orElse y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val minValue: Int = List(i1, i2).flatten.sorted.headOption getOrElse defaultValue
```

Answer (score 2):

We can combine the 2 `Option`s as an `Iterable` with `Option`'s [`++`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#++[B%3E:A,That](that:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That) operator, which allows us to use [`minOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Iterable.html#minOption:Option[A]) (to nicely handle the case of the empty iterable formed by the `None/None` case) and fallback on a default value if necessary with `getOrElse`:

```
(optionA ++ optionB).minOption.getOrElse(-1)
// None and None       => -1
// Some(5) and None    => 5
// None and Some(5)    => 5
// Some(5) and Some(3) => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use patterns in for expressions, values that do not match the pattern are discarded.

```
(for (Some(x) <- List(None, Some(3))) yield x) max
```

Not as good as the List.flatten approach though.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which wasn't mentioned is using `reduceLeftOption` (interchange `math.max` and `math.min` as desired):

```
val min = (first ++ second).reduceLeftOption(math.min).getOrElse(defaultValue)
```

---

```
scala> val first = Some(10)
first: Some[Int] = Some(10)

scala> val second: Option[Int] = None
second: Option[Int] = None

scala> val defaultMin = -1
defaultMin: Int = -1

scala> (first ++ second).reduceLeftOption(math.min).getOrElse(defaultMin)
res7: Int = 10

scala> val first: Option[Int] = None
first: Option[Int] = None

scala> (first ++ second).reduceLeftOption(math.min).getOrElse(defaultMin)
res8: Int = -1

scala> val first = Some(10)
first: Some[Int] = Some(10)

scala> val second = Some(42)
second: Some[Int] = Some(42)

scala> (first ++ second).reduceLeftOption(math.min).getOrElse(defaultMin)
res9: Int = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using scalaz and map/for/getOrElse, you can do the following:

```
val minValue = (i1, i2) match {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => math.min(x, y)
  case _ => defaultValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but I wanted the min value if either one was defined, not only when both are defined.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

You can do that you need elegant using custom **cats** `Semigroup` instances:

```scala
import cats.kernel.Semigroup
import cats.instances.option._ // this import is for cats std option combiner
import cats.syntax.semigroup._

object Implicits {
 implicit val intMinSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] =
   (x: Int, y: Int) => math.min(x, y)

 implicit val intMaxSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] =
   (x: Int, y: Int) => math.max(x, y)
}
 
import Implicits.intMinSemigroup
// these are results for minSemigroup
// List((Some(1),Some(1),Some(2)), (Some(1),Some(1),None), (None,Some(2),Some(2)), (None,None,None))
//import Implicits.intMaxSemigroup
// these are results for maxSemigroup
// List((Some(1),Some(2),Some(2)), (Some(1),Some(1),None), (None,Some(2),Some(2)), (None,None,None))
   
for {
 maybeA <- Seq(Some(1), None)
 maybeB <- Seq(Some(2), None)
} yield (maybeA, maybeA |+| maybeB, maybeB)
```

if you want replace `None` by default value you can use combine twice:

```scala
val defaultValue: Int = 3
val optionMin = for {
  maybeA <- Seq(Some(1), None)
  maybeB <- Seq(Some(2), None)
} yield (maybeA |+| maybeB) |+| Some(defaultValue)
// List(Some(1), Some(1), Some(2), Some(3))
```

### How it works

Shortly, `Semigroup[A]` is *typeclass* for **combining** two values of the same type `A` into the one value of type `A`.
Here we use std cats `OptionMonoid` (it extends `Semigroup[Option[A]]`) here source code:

```scala
class OptionMonoid[A](implicit A: Semigroup[A]) extends Monoid[Option[A]] {
  def empty: Option[A] = None
  def combine(x: Option[A], y: Option[A]): Option[A] =
    x match {
      case None => y
      case Some(a) =>
        y match {
          case None    => x
          case Some(b) => Some(A.combine(a, b))
        }
    }
}
```

We see that it takes option matching on his own and everything what we should give him to work is `implicit A: Semigroup[A]`. In our case we write two different combiners for `min`, `max` cases:

```scala
object Implicits {
 implicit val intMinSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] =
   (x: Int, y: Int) => math.min(x, y)

 implicit val intMaxSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] =
   (x: Int, y: Int) => math.max(x, y)
}
```

So, we import combiners (i.e. `import Implicits.intMinSemigroup`) and just use `cats.syntax.semigroup` for using **combine** function as operator `|+|`:

`maybeA |+| maybeB`.

In conclusion, you can just define your custom **semigroup** for *any type* (not only `Int`) and **combine** options of this type after importing some **cats** *syntax* and *instances*.